# Using Split function to insert into array

Tags: java, split

I'm trying to transfer a "data.txt" file into database.the txt file contains data packets

```
(**S12*T0*0889*B*99*N1C0~**S12*T0*0880*B*99*N1C0~**S12*T0*0889*B*99*N1C0~)...
```

here's my code to separate the data based on "~":

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
String token1 = "";// create token1 (deceleration only)
List<String> temps = new ArrayList<String>();// Array Deceleration only 
Scanner inFile1 = new Scanner(new File("2.txt"));
inFile1.useDelimiter("~ *");
while (inFile1.hasNext()) {// while loop
  token1 = inFile1.next();// find next line in inFile1
  temps.add(token1); 
}   
inFile1.close();`
```

now i also need to separate the data between the "*" and insert into the database.Code for database insertion:

```
String[] tempsArray = temps.toArray(new String[0]); 
PreparedStatement ps = null;
  try{
      Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");//Data Source Driver
      Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:testing");//Data Connection
      for(String s : tempsArray){   
          ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into testing (fileName)values('"+s+"')");//inserting data
          System.out.println(s);//printing inserted data
          System.out.println("inserted");//insertion confirmation
          ps.executeUpdate();
      }
      con.close();
 }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }      
}
```

}

- How do i use multiple Delimiters on the same file(is it possible to extract in 1 go?)
- how do i put the data in to the database(i found that you have to put it in an array ,confused with the syntax(s))
- lastly when i insert into database can i just use :PreparedStateme...("insert... (fileN...('"+s+"',array[1],array[2])"),where array 1 and array 2 are the second and third elements of the data after extraction between "*".

Comment: Not related to the question, just wanted to tell you: You are using the `PreparedStatement` entirely wrong! Never put dynamic content into the SQL of a prepared statement! Have a look at [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). You should prepare the statement once and execute it multiple times with different data.

Comment: i used due to real time incoming data.

Comment: i have made edits to the code.

Comment: Welcome to Java. Sorry, you did not improve anything. Moving the declaration out of the loop fixes none of the problems. Have a look at examples of using prepared statements.